# Making a dynamic button so user can invite just one person per day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created an application where a user can invite someone to a certain hour of training every day. I would like that when the user has already invited someone, the button disappears in other training sessions and when it gets in the show of the training he invited the user the button "Cancel invitation" appears. I already have the method of Create and Delete. I need help with this code logic.

These are my models (User, Guest and Training):

training.rb

```
class Training < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users, through: :bookings
  has_many :bookings
  has_many :guests
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :trainings, through: :bookings
  has_many :bookings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :guests, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :guests
end
```

guest.rb

```
class Guest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :training
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :training_id, presence: true
  validate :training_not_full?, on: :create 
 end
```

config routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'static_pages#home'
  get    '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  get    '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get    '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'


  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resources :users do
    resources :rms
  end


  resources :trainings do
    resources :guests
    resources :bookings
  end
end
```

This is the logic I've tried (not working though):

```
<% if current_user.trainings.any? %>
  <%= link_to "Cancel invitation", 
      training_guest_path(@training, @training.guests.where(user: current_user).first), 
      method: :delete, 
      data: { confirm: "Sure??" }, 
      class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Invite", new_training_guest_path(current_user), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What's exaxtly not workking? The delete button? Or what?

Comment: just for reference, read those -  1) https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services 2) https://www.netguru.co/blog/service-objects-in-rails-will-help you'll know

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon everything is working, but i need the logic to that when user has already invited someone it cant invite someone else to another class, and just cancel the invite it has already active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `Invitation` model as below:

```
class CreateInvitations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :invitations do |t|
      t.string :user_id
      t.string :guest_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class Invitation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :guests
end
```

and then check if the user already invited a guest in past 24 hours:

```
last_invitation_date = user.invitations.order(:created_at).last.created_at
can_invite = last_invitation_date < DateTime.now - 1.day
```

Comment: i should add the last_invitation_date to the invitation model right?

Comment: It can't be. Because we extract last invitation date from the user object. You can create a method inside the user model named `can_invite?` and put the last 2 lines that checks if user can invite guests inside it.